# Accordion closes when I change value of a form within it

Tags: reactjs, react-bootstrap

I've got an Accordion that has within it a text form (code sandbox: https://codesandbox.io/live/1qr00im):

```
function MovementAccordion() {
  const [formInput, setFormInput] = useState('')

    return(
      <Accordion>
        <Card>
          <Accordion.Toggle
            as={Card.Header}
            eventKey="0">
            Accordian Header
          </Accordion.Toggle>
          <Accordion.Collapse eventKey="0">
            <Card.Body>
              Fill in the form:
              <Form.Control
                onChange={(event) => setFormInput(event.target.value)}
                type="text"
                placeholder="Enter input here" />
              <Button
                variant="primary"
                >
                  Add
              </Button>
            </Card.Body>
          </Accordion.Collapse>
        </Card>
      </Accordion>
    )
  }
```

I've added an onChange() function to the Form so that any time the form is updated it is pushed to state. However, any time the Form is updated the Accordion closes.

If I remove the onChange() function altogether, the form works fine and I can update it at will. The issue comes whenever the onChange() is included.

After spending more time than I'd like to admit trying to find a fix this, I'm stuck.

Comment: You should create a minimal reproducible example (preferably on [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/))

Comment: @hgb123 Done: https://codesandbox.io/live/1qr00im

Comment: The accordion is not closing in the codesandbox example

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to your [sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/live/1qr00im):-

- you should not call your `function` like you call a normal `JSX` `functional component`. Instead you should've just called it like how normal `function` should be called - `{PrimaryMovementAccordion()}`
- if you want to called like the current state you're now. Then that would only be achievable if the `SecondaryMovementAccordion` is indeed a `JSX` `functional component`. So you need to create another `React Functional Component` of `SecondaryMovementAccordion`, like so, in order to make it work:-
- in `App.js`:-

```js
import React, { useState } from "react";
import "bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css";
import "./styles.css";

import Accordion from "react-bootstrap/Accordion";
import Card from "react-bootstrap/Card";
import Form from "react-bootstrap/Form";
import Button from "react-bootstrap/Button";

import SecondaryMovementAccordion from "./SecondaryMovementAccordion";

export default function App() {
  const [newPrimary, setNewPrimary] = useState("");
  const [newSecondary, setNewSecondary] = useState("");

  return (
    <>
      {/* Incorrect way of calling normal function */}
      {/* <PrimaryMovementAccordion /> */}
      {/* correct way of calling a normal function */}
      {PrimaryMovementAccordion()}
      {/* correct way of calling a JSX Functional Component */}
      <SecondaryMovementAccordion
        newSecondary={newSecondary}
        setNewSecondary={setNewSecondary}
      />
      <p>Primary: {newPrimary}</p>
      <p>Secondary: {newSecondary}</p>
    </>
  );

  // Primary Accordian
  function PrimaryMovementAccordion() {
    return (
      <Accordion defaultActiveKey="0">
        <Card>
          <Accordion.Toggle as={Card.Header} eventKey="0">
            Form accordion
          </Accordion.Toggle>
          <Accordion.Collapse eventKey="0">
            <Card.Body>
              Fill in the form:
              <Form.Control
                type="text"
                placeholder="Enter secondary movement"
                value={newPrimary}
                onChange={(event) => setNewPrimary(event.target.value)}
              />
              <p>{newPrimary}</p>
            </Card.Body>
          </Accordion.Collapse>
        </Card>
      </Accordion>
    );
  }
}
```

- `SecondaryMovementAccordion.js`:-

```js
import React from "react";
import "bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css";
import "./styles.css";

import Accordion from "react-bootstrap/Accordion";
import Card from "react-bootstrap/Card";
import Form from "react-bootstrap/Form";
import Button from "react-bootstrap/Button";

const SecondaryMovementAccordion = ({ newSecondary, setNewSecondary }) => {
  return (
    <Accordion defaultActiveKey="0">
      <Card>
        <Accordion.Toggle as={Card.Header} eventKey="0">
          Form accordion
        </Accordion.Toggle>
        <Accordion.Collapse eventKey="0">
          <Card.Body>
            Fill in the form:
            <Form.Control
              type="text"
              placeholder="Enter secondary movement"
              value={newSecondary}
              onChange={(event) => setNewSecondary(event.target.value)}
            />
            <p>{newSecondary}</p>
          </Card.Body>
        </Accordion.Collapse>
      </Card>
    </Accordion>
  );
};

export default SecondaryMovementAccordion;
```

This is the working [sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/misty-hill-gwx5s?file=/src/App.js) shown above.